# Remove anchor tags from a paragraph but keep the text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, text

I'm getting text from a backend api in this form:

```
const serverText = "This is a <a href="http://www.link1">link</a> and so is <a href="http://www.link1">this</a>. This is also another <a href="http://www.link2">boring link</a>.";
```

I'm looking to get it into this form:

```
const formatted = "This is a link and so is this. This is also another boring link.";
```

I played around with this with regex but I'm not sure if this is the way to go since it's just outputting an array of the found words.

Is there an easier way to do this with vanilla Javascript without using any extra DOM tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var yourHtml= `This is a <a href="http://www.link1">link</a> and so is <a href="http://www.link1">this</a>. This is also another <a href="http://www.link2">boring link</a>.`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(yourHtml, 'text/html');

var text = htmlDoc.body.innerText;

console.log(text); // Returns: "This is a link and so is this. This is also another boring link."
```

This converts your HTML string into DOM, and uses `.innerText` to remove all html elements from your string - leaving only the text.

### Update:

Created this simple function that returns text, and only requires the HTML string:

```js
function textFromHTML(str) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return htmlDoc.body.innerText;
}

/* --- Usage --- */

var yourHtml= `This is a <a href="http://www.link1">link</a> and so is <a href="http://www.link1">this</a>. This is also another <a href="http://www.link2">boring link</a>.`;
var text = textFromHTML(yourHtml);

console.log(text); // Returns text
```

### Update 2 (RegEx):

Final version, but uses RegExp instead of the `DOMParser()`:

```js
function textFromHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("<.*?>", "g"), "");
}

/* --- Usage --- */

var text = textFromHTML("Hello <span>World!</span> This string is HTML!");

console.log(text); // Returns: "Hello World! This string is HTML!"
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but I'm afraid the DOMParser won't work for me.  I'm using a JS library (Nativescript) that don't use a real DOM so those awesome tools won't work.  I may need to construct brute force solution.

Comment: @razorsyntax Ahhh right, I will look into a different solution in that case.

Comment: @razorsyntax Made a solution using RegEx - feel free to check it out on my answer.